# SetAttribute CheckBox checked is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am generating a dynamic table, adding a row to it and then assigning some properties to the elements added in those cells.
Everything is working fine except for checkbox set or reset. In function `display_start_time()`, the command

```
document.getElementById(domain).checked = false;
```

is not working for the rows dynamically generated. When I throw a static table to this function, it works properly. The problem may be with the setAttribute function (using IE10, Windows 8) as I have tried going through many solutions online but not able to make a breakthrough in this one. One of the solution provided is to change over to jquery but that  has few problems with me.

1. I don't know jquery
2. It will take me some significant time in learning and then changing my entire code according to jquery.

Function `Report` is called onclick a button to create a new row.
`display_time(domain,range);` works fine.

Please guide me. Script starts here

```
function display_start_time(domain, range, user_id, process_id, process_name)
{    
    if(!document.getElementById(user_id).innerHTML)
    {       
        alert("Please select the server");
        document.getElementById(domain).checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        question= confirm("Have you STARTED the " + domain + " of " + process_id + " ? ");  
        {
            if(question)
                display_time(domain,range);
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(domain).checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function report(set_id,btn_id)
{ 
    question= confirm("Has the error occurred ?");  
    if(question)
    {
        new_table = document.getElementById("isolop_table");
        row = new_table.insertRow();
        cell_1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell_2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell_3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell_4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell_5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell_6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell_7 = row.insertCell(6);
        cell_8 = row.insertCell(7);
        cell_9 = row.insertCell(8);

        //  Inserting Data in Isolop Table Rows
        cell_1.innerHTML = serial;
        cell_2.innerHTML = document.getElementById(set_id).innerHTML;
        cell_2.setAttribute("id", "Int" + serial);
        cell_4.innerHTML = cell_5.id;
        cell_4.setAttribute("id","user_id"+serial);
        cell_7.innerHTML = "Start Time";
        cell_7.setAttribute("id","disp_start"+serial);
        cell_8.innerHTML = "End Time";
        cell_8.setAttribute("id","disp_end"+serial);
        cell_5.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' ></input>";
        cell_5.setAttribute("id", "INT"+serial);
        //          cell_5.setAttribute("checked", 'true');
        cell_5.setAttribute('onclick',"display_start_time(cell_5.id,cell_7.id,cell_4.id,cell_2.innerHTML,'ISOLOP')");

        cell_4.innerHTML = cell_5.id;
        cell_6.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'></input>";
        cell_6.setAttribute("id", "end"+serial);
        cell_6.setAttribute('onclick',"display_end_time(cell_6.id,cell_8.id,cell_5.id,cell_2.innerHTML,'ISOLOP');");
        cell_9.innerHTML = " <button type='button' onclick=report('Int1');>Report Error</button>";
        document.getElementById(btn_id).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(btn_id).onclick = false;
        return serial++;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you're using the same global variables `cell_1` through `cell_9` every time you add a row to the table. When the user clicks on one of the cells, the variables will refer to the cells in the last row that was added, not the row they're clicking on.

Comment: I have not tried more than 1 row yet. It should atleast work for 1 row.

Comment: If you're planning on extending it to multiple rows, don't waste time trying to get this design to work, since you'll have to redo it anyway. Use Joel's answer.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. However, my idea is to disable the row when a new row has been added. I have tried doing document.getElementById(btn_id).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(btn_id).onclick = false;
to disable the button. It changes it appearance to that of disabled but still, when clicked, it creates a new row. That is another problem I am facing in addition to the current one. Also I have tried Joel's answer but that's not working either..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from this line:

```
cell_5.setAttribute('onclick',"display_start_time(cell_5.id,cell_7.id,cell_4.id,cell_2.innerHTML,'ISOLOP')");
```

When you set the onclick handler as a string, it is executed within the global context of the page, not the context in which you set the handler. If cell_5, cell_7, etc. do not exist in the global context, the function will fail.

Try using addEventListener or setting onclick with an anonymous function as the event handler. The cell_# variables will be captured inside its scope, so it should function like you expect.

```
cell_5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    display_start_time(cell_5.id, cell_7.id, cell_4.id, cell_2.innerHTML, 'ISOLOP');
}, false);
```

OR

```
cell_5.onclick = function() {
    display_start_time(cell_5.id, cell_7.id, cell_4.id, cell_2.innerHTML, 'ISOLOP');
}
```

Likewise, you should do this for the click handler on cell_6.

Comment: I have used a confirm box stating                                       question= confirm("Have you STARTED the " + domain + " of " +  process_id + " ? "); It shows me the correct values.. Also the function display_time(domain,range);
takes the same values and yet working good.

Comment: His variables are all global variables, so they should be available in the scope where the `onclick` is executed.

Comment: Make sure you declare the variables as local variables for this solution to work.

Comment: That is a bit tricky.. As per the studies, I have made over php, ajax and javascript any variable declared inside a function should be local and out side function would be global. According to it, only 'serial' variable is a global variable and rest all are local variables. Also all of my code is working except for that checked thing..

Comment: Oh. I'm surprised I missed this until now: you are changing the checked attribute of cell_5, which is the cell itself, not the checkbox input inside the cell. You either need to set the ID on the input element instead of the cell, or use some extra logic to find the input inside the cell.